# What is the locus of a map?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory

1. What is the  locus of a map? I search the definition of locus in the Wikipedia, it explains the locus as follows:

   In geometry, a locus is a set of all points , whose location satisfies or is determined by one or more specified conditions.

   So, what is the locus of a map?
2. Further more, what is the meaning of the sign $\mathbb{N}^r$?

   Thanks!

Comment: You should probably include the whole context for the first question. This will help people to give the right definition. As for the second, it is simply the Cartesian product of $\mathbb N$ (the natural numbers) with itself $r$ times.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I have known the answer of the first question.